# 'LIKE' or 'NOT LIKE' that is the question

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm wondering if there is any particular performance advantage in using `LIKE` over `NOT LIKE` or vice versa. For example:

say I have 1000 rows (yes not very many, but after all this is an example) and only 50 have the word `world` in its `hello` column after querying the db using

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE hello LIKE'%world%'
```

or

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE hello NOT LIKE '%world%'
```

`LIKE` returns `50` while using `NOT LIKE` returns `950`
My question is not on which you should use in any particular scenario but rather if there is any performance cost for which you use as both will have to 'search' the entire table anyway
**:)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no performance difference.  `NOT` just inverts the result of whatever follows it.  The logical inversion is an extremely quick operation, taking just a few nanoseconds on a modern processor....

All of the expense will be related to the number of rows selected, and tracking them for other parts of the query.

Comment: If on the other hand one of the queries returns *a lot* of rows, while the other return few rows, there'll be performance cost with with handling all that data, sending ot over the wire, etc. (though for just 1000 rows this overhead is negligible)

Comment: This is what I first thought, but just wanted to check with the more 'knowledgeable' on the subject

Comment: @nos: Agree, but the answer seems to have covered that with the statement: `All of the expense will be related to the number of rows selected`.

Answer (score 1):

Logically speaking, no they are equal in performance.